# Relating two comboboxes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have a WPF Application with two `ComboBox`es.
When I select the first one the items related  to the first combobox will be populated on the second one

Here is my select Property

```
   public string SelectedApplication
    {
        set
        {
            if (_selectedApplication == value) return;
            this._selectedApplication = value;

            InitializeTransactionTypes();


        }
        get
        {
            return this._selectedApplication;
        }

    }
```

here i am checking a matching id between the two comboboxes to populate the second control items.

```
    ObservableCollection<TransactionTypeViewModel> _transTypeObsList = new ObservableCollection<TransactionTypeViewModel>();
       private void InitializeTransactionTypes()
    {
        if (_selectedApplication != null)
        {
            if (transactionTypes != null)
            {
                transactionTypes.Clear();
            }

            var getAppCode =
                ApplicationVModel.GetAllApplications().FirstOrDefault(apps => apps.Name == _selectedApplication);

            var transTypeList = TransactionTypeVModel.GetAllTransactionTypes()
                                                     .Where(t => getAppCode != null && t.Id == getAppCode.Id)
                                                     .ToList();

            _transTypeObsList = new ObservableCollection<TransactionTypeViewModel>(transTypeList);
        }
        this.transactionTypes = _transTypeObsList;

        NotifyPropertyChanged("TransactionTypes");
    }
```

Lets say I select first combobox has {A,B,C,D} ...and the second combobox has  {A'1,A'2,A'3}, when I select item from first Combobox the second combobo keeps populating 
items. I wanted to show only {A'1 for A} {B'1 for B} ...etc but now what it does is  {A'1  A'1 A'1 ..... for A} {B'1 B'1 B'1 ....for B} for every select.

EDIT:

List of VM mapped from List of Model

```
       public List<TransactionTypeViewModel> GetAllViewModelTransTypes()
    {
        TransactionTypeViewModels =   TransactionTypeModel.GetAllTransactionTypes().Select(transType => new TransactionTypeViewModel
        {
            Id = transType.Id,
            Name = transType.Name,
            RequestMessageType = transType.RequestMessageType,
            ResponseMessageTypes = transType.ResponseMessageTypes,
            WsMethodName = transType.WSMethodName,
            WsRequestXmlType = transType.WSRequestXmlType,
            WsResponseXmlType = transType.WSResponseXmlType,
            XsdFile = transType.XsdFile,

        })
    .ToList();
        return TransactionTypeViewModels;
    }
```

List of Observable VM from List of VM

```
     public ObservableCollection<TransactionTypeViewModel> GetAllTransactionTypes()
    {
        TransactionTypeViewModelList = this.GetAllViewModelTransTypes();
        ObservableTransactionType = new ObservableCollection<TransactionTypeViewModel>(TransactionTypeViewModelList);

        return ObservableTransactionType;
    }
```

EDIT:

```
  private void InitializeTransactionTypes()
    {
        if (_selectedApplication != null)
        {

            var getAppCode =
                ApplicationVModel.GetAllApplications()
                                 .FirstOrDefault(apps => apps.Name == _selectedApplication);

            var transTypeList = TransactionTypeVModel.GetAllTransactionTypes()
                                                     .Where(t => getAppCode != null && t.Id == getAppCode.Id);

            transactionTypes = new ObservableCollection<TransactionTypeViewModel>(transTypeList); 

           NotifyPropertyChanged("TransactionTypes");
        }
    }
```

Comment: In MVVM you would typically have one `ObservableCollection` property in the ViewModel populated for each `ComboBox`. Each `ComboBox.ItemsSource` would define a binding to those ViewModel collections.  You also bind the `SelectedItem` property of each ComboBox to a backing VM property. In the setter of the first 'selected' property is where you want to populate your second collection. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: @AdolfoPerez That is exactly what I am doing.. one observable collection for each control and populate the second collection in the setter of the first selected property ..I updated my original post

Comment: How many Items are in transTypeList?

Comment: @jfin3204 i have two right now but when i select it duplicates ..

Comment: @AydaSayed So the number of items in transTypeList gets bigger with every selection?  What is the code for GetAllTransactionTypes()?

Comment: What's the relation between `this.transactionTypes` and `_transTypeObsList` as I don't definition of either? Is `transactionTypes` your public property? If so you notify wrong property `NotifyPropertyChanged("TransactionTypes");` as it's case sensitive

Comment: @jfin3204 yes that is right ... I updated the method u asked on the edit section of my post

Comment: Maybe it's because you have a recusive call. `GetAllViewModelTransTypes` uses `GetAllTransactionTypes` which uses `GetAllViewModelTransTypes`

Comment: @AydaSayed you are returning an Observable collection from GetAllTransactionTypes and then casting it to a list, then adding the list to a new observable collection.  Does anything else call GetAllTransactionTypes?    IF you put a break point in GetAllTransactionTypes how many times does it get hit.  How many times does it get hit after a select, then a second select?

Comment: @jfin3204 updated my code this time i called observable list and i didn't change it to list I just assign it to my transactiontype. when i debug forst time it bring two items, second time it bring s four items. I start to wonder maybe my GetAllViewModelTransTypes method is not working properly

Comment: @dkozl Comment about having a recursive call could be your issue? What about refactoring and adding the select from  GetAllViewModelTransTypes into GetAllTransactionTypes then removing TransactionTypeViewModelList = this.GetAllViewModelTransTypes();

Comment: @dkozl  let me try it out

Comment: @dkozl I commented out GetAllViewModelTransTypes() and made a select from GetAllViewModelTransTypes  but still the same.

Comment: @jfin3204 I commented out GetAllViewModelTransTypes() and made a select from GetAllViewModelTransTypes  but still the same.